# Unauthorized tab under Agents missing- Team City

Tags: teamcity, build-agent

In just installed a build agent and configured it with required parameters. Logged onto the dashboard and under Agents, I do not see Unauthorized tab and so not see any indication of the new build agent I configured.

I started the agent and it is running on a remote server.

Is there a reason why I do not see the Unauthorized tab? Please help!

Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a permissions issue - is it possible the user you are logged in as doesn't have the "authorize project agent" permissions?